# Получить ID картинки зная лишь ее путь (Bitrix API)

Tags: php, файлы, битрикс

Подскажите как можно простым способом получить ID картинки зная лишь путь к файлу (*/upload/iblock/212/21232121288522265c927d1df55305f8.jpg*)?

Нужна обратная функция **CFile::GetByID**. Вроде как-то можно через **CFile::GetList**, но не могу понять как.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
function getFileIdBySrc($strFilename){
    $strUploadDir = '/'.\Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::get('main', 'upload_dir').'/';
    $strFile = substr($strFilename, strlen($strUploadDir));
    $strSql = "SELECT ID FROM b_file WHERE CONCAT(SUBDIR, '/', FILE_NAME) = '{$strFile}'";
    return \Bitrix\Main\Application::getConnection()->query($strSql)->fetch()['ID'];
}
```

Использовать так:

```
print getFileIdBySrc('/upload/iblock/212/21232121288522265c927d1df55305f8.jpg');
```

Готового способа нет, поэтому функция выполняет несколько действий:

1. определяет путь к файлу без начального /upload/,
2. ищет в БД файл, который лежит по такому пути (в БД подпапка iblock/212 и имя файла 21232121288522265c927d1df55305f8.jpg хранятся в разных полях, поэтому применяется CONCAT).